# error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating'this.props'). react-native expo

Tags: javascript, react-native

1. Here is my Login.js:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Logo />
  <Form type="Login"/>
  <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
    <Text style={styles.signupText}> D'ont have an account yet? </Text>
    <Text style={styles.signupButton}> Signup </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

2. Here is my Signup.js:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Logo />
  <Form type="Signup"/>
  <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
    <Text style={styles.signupText}> Already have an account yet? </Text>
    <Text style={styles.signupButton}> Sign in </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

3. and my Form.js:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    placeholder= "Email"
    placeholderTextColor= "#ffffff"
  />
  <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
    underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    placeholder= "Password"
    secureTextEntry= {true}
    placeholderTextColor= "#ffffff"
  />

  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I'm agree with you. But I'm a new user of this site, so did not now all the rules.

Comment: You don't need to vote! I was just looking for help .

Answer (score 0):

this.props.type has to be passed to the `<text/>` component from your global/app component (where your state object should sit) - using the browser's dev tools, look at your React components to see where your state object is.

Use the this keyword to pass props data to your `<text/>` component from your global/app component:

```
<text type={this.props.type}/>
```

If your components are split into individual .js files, make sure your global/app component has access to your `<text/>` component using module import/export.

Comment: this is my app.js file :

Comment: import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

import Login from './src/pages/Login';
import Signup from './src/pages/Signup';

export default function App() {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="#fe7751"
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <Signup />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#4d37b5',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

Comment: I create a login.js file and register.js file importing the form.js inside them.

Comment: I have also declared  in form.js : <Form type="Login"/> and in signup.js : <Form type="Signup"/>

Comment: so in form if I try this : <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> I got the Error.

Answer (score 0):

My compenet is not a class but a function.
if the component is not a class we can't use this.props.
the solution is:
in Form add props like that Form(props) and instead of this.props.type, we add juste props.type.